# merge segments with ffmpeg causes small cracks in the audio

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, spark-streaming

To speed up the delivery of videos on my platform I split the uploaded medias into segments of up to 120 seconds and process them simultaneously on several machines.

After processing, I put the pieces back together with "-f concat".

Unfortunately, new media is generated with small cracks in the audio (*they occur exactly at the junction*). I haven't found a filter / command yet to end the problem. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Note: I am using ffmpeg 3.4.1

**This is the command I make to split the media:**

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -fflags +genpts -avoid_negative_ts make_zero -y -v error -i /video/somevideo.mov -map 0:v? -map 0:a? -c copy -f segment -segment_time 120 -segment_format matroska -reset_timestamps 1 -segment_list_type ffconcat -segment_list /video/segment_map.ffcat /video/segment%03d
```

**A short example of the command used to process a segment**

some variables change according to the resolution

```
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -v error -probesize 10M -analyzeduration 10M -itsoffset 0.066 -i /video/segment000 -c:v libx264 -preset fast -profile:v high -crf 23 -r 117375/3916 -maxrate 1500000 -bufsize 2250000 -g 58 -keyint_min 58 -sc_threshold 0 -bf 3 -b_strategy 2 -refs 10 -vf scale="iw*sar:ih,scale=trunc(oh*a/2)*2:540" -pix_fmt yuv420p -max_muxing_queue_size 5000 -strict -2 -c:a aac -b:a 128000 -ar 44100  -f mp4 /video/transcode/segment000
```

**to finalize how do I join the segments**

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -v error -f concat -safe 0 -y -i /video/transcode/segment_map.ffcat -c copy -movflags +faststart /video/transcoded.mp4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible to join audio this way. You must convert the entire Audio track in a single pass, then mux it into the result.